# Two flanges underneath toilet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, repair, toilet

Little outside my wheel house here. I took up a toilet in a new (to me) property to re-seat it with a new wax ring, and found two flanges underneath, with a lot of corrosion looks like [image: two flanges]

The white flange actually came off with the toilet. There were the typical 2 bolts holding the toilet to the floor, but I didn't see anything else - looks like the bolts were bolting the toilet to the white flange. This is a lower level of a split level home, so on concrete slab.

What do I do here? It doesn't seem like using a new wax ring and attaching it to the white flange would be sufficient - do I need to find some other bolts?

Comment: that second flange is not a flange it is a spacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it looks like is that you have a Ceramic Floor.

You need to use two flanges - the reason for this setup is that the pipe flange does not sit high enough for the toilet to properly seat against - the tile height is a problem its a bit too high. So the common procedure is to install a spacer or extender flange. Typically you will have a Caulking to Form a Gasket between the two lower flanges. Clink my link below to get the details.

[Here](http://allthumbsdiy.com/plumbing/toilet-flange-too-low-double-wax-ring-or-extender-spacer-kit) is the options and a more detailed layout of what and why and how to resolve the issue.

[How to remove a metal flange](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/how-to/how-to-repair-cast-iron-toilet-flange) toilet gasket and replace it - some ideas for repair are included.

Comment: Thanks Ken, but its actually tile-look linoleum floor

Comment: @Chris it still has to do with the height of the floor - that is the reason this is done - the floor height is higher than the flange from your toilet drain pipe. The second flange is added as a spacer so the wax ring meats the flange - otherwise a bunch of crap - sewage will flow from the toilet into your bathroom where the toilet is supposed to meet the drain.

Comment: Gotcha; how's this? Since the original red flange is rusted, I need to break or pry that out, then set a new inner fitting flange there secured with concrete screws, then attach the extender flange to the inner fitting flange, and the wax ring, etc on top of that?

Comment: @Chris your red flange may be attached to the metal pipe probably needs to be unscrewed. After 20 or 30 years - expect it to be difficult, you might need to saw a line in it to remove it. I will post a video for how to remove a metal flange I think it will be very helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

the second flange is not a flange it is a spacer so there is no problem

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You should improve this answer because as it stands it is being flagged as low quality and is in danger of being deleted.

Comment: Michael karas that is all i can think of there is no more that i can add thats is all there i to it.